# Is there an equivalent of "little Willie" poems in Italian?

Tags: resources

Are there any extremely popular short funny verses, which had become "memes" long before this word was invented?

Example (warning: black humour, possible triggers):
*Little Willie hung his sister

She was dead before we missed her.

Willies always up to tricks

Ain`t he cute? He's only six.*

Something like this will do, too:
*Down the river drifts an axe

From the town of Byron.

Let it float by itself,

B###dy piece of iron.*

Comment: Tipo Ambarabà ciccì coccò? https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambarab%C3%A0_cicc%C3%AC_cocc%C3%B2

Comment: Are you searching for a generic term? Maybe "filastrocca"

Comment: Could you clarify a bit your question? Are you literally just asking “Are there any extremely popular short funny verses...?”? If so, the answer is “Yes, of course”. Do you want to know Italian terms for “short funny verses”? Do you need examples of such (somewhat off-topic)? Something else?

Comment: @DaG It's not very clear from the question, but it appears that "little Willie poems" are a specific kind of macabre poetry in English (http://ruthlessrhymes.com/category/little_willies/little-willie-poems)

Comment: Thank you, @DenisNardin, I have learned something new. But then the title seems to refer to something different and more specific than the actual phrasing of the question.

Comment: L'unica analogia che mi viene in mente è con le filastrocche di Piero: "C'era una volta
Piero si volta.
Casca la lira,
Piero si gira.
Casca la rosa,
Piero si sposa.
Casca la scopa,
Piero s'accoppa"

Comment: @MareManeski: Are you still interested in an answer? If so, could you please clarify which traits of these short poems are you interested in? Yes, in Italian there are short, catchy poems. No, there aren't about someone called “little Willie”. Maybe, there might be some showing some kind of black humour. If you can make your question more precise, someone'll be glad to answer.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot I had asked something here. @DaG, actually. I've been looking for dark humour.

Comment: @user84976 Yes, this folklore character is what I had in mind.